# Shipping commission calculation using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a product payment page with shipping system. But I don't know how to calculate if else in javascript or jquery, also I don't know how I use % (parcentage) in javascript.

Any genius here who can help me to give a idea about this? I'm newbee on javascript. So Please help me before give a negative vote. If you think its very easy then please give me idea or example. I tried it search on google, stackoverflow and jsfiddle.

Here is idea what I want?

```
Food + DHL = Shipment cost 3%
Food + Fedex = Shipment cost 2.5%
Food + Post = Shipment cost 0.2%

Furnitures + DHL = shipment cost 4%
Furnitures + FedEx = shipment cost 2%
Furnitures + Post = shipment cost 1%

Cars + DHL = Shipment cost 5%
Cars + FedEx = Shipment 6%
When select cars, post option will be disable and can't be selected. 

When select Computers, DHL option will be disable and can't be selected. 
When select Computers, FedEx option will be disable and can't be selected.
Computers + Post = Shipment cost 3%
```

How I apply those cost using javascript or jquery?
When user input amount on field.

```
    <form action="payment.php">
    <label>Please select your product type</label>
    <select name="product-type" id="ptype">
    <option value="Food">Food</option>
    <option value="Furnitures">Furnitures</option>
    <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
    <option value="Computers">Computers</option>
    </select>

    <label>Shipment System</label>
    <select name="shipment" id="shipment">
    <option value="DHL">DHL (4-5 days)</option>
    <option value="FedEx">FedEx (4-5 days)</option>
    <option value="Post">Regular Post (15-30 days)</option>
    </select>

    <label>Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="price">

    <!-- here I want to put amount of money. its will be use for shipment costing. -->

    <label>Shipment Cost</label>
    <span class="text_decoration" id="shipment_cost">0</span>% 
    <!-- I think here will be automatically added shipment %, when user select product type and shipment system. -->

    <!-- Shipment cost % automatically added with total price. so total price will be amount + shipment cost. -->

    <label>Total Price</label>
    $<span class="text_decoration" id="total_price">0</span>

    <button id="payment" name="submit">Confirm & Pay</button>

    </form>
```

Is it possible? Any easy method? I'm really newbee and want to learn from all of senior and javascript genius. Please help me to learn and use js.

Comment: Food + DHL = Shipment cost 3%..Does that mean that (Food + DHL) is 3% of the shipment cost?

Comment: Percentage is just a decimal fraction.  For 3%, it is 0.03.  To get 3% of something, multiply by 0.03

Comment: I'd suggest looking at some tutorials on JavaScript first, because if you don't know how to use "if...else", would you actually understand the help that people might give you?

Comment: I agree with all of above comments, NEVERTHELESS I have added an answer with javascript function that should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so this seems to be the way to achieve this. Its not possible to disable/hide options (unless we are willing to take quite long way to achieve that) I have made it so a alert is issuer if compitable pairs are not available.

You can see how I made pairs in `json` just add `null` as value for pair which you don't want to exist.

(Of course you will need to include `jquery.min.js` file.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fees    =   { "food_dhl": 3, "food_fedex": 2.5, "food_post": 0.2, "furnitures_dhl": 4, "furnitures_fedex" : 2, "furnitures_post" : 1, "cars_dhl" : 5, "cars_fedex" : 6, "cars_post" : null, "computers_post" : 3 };

function _shipment_fee() {
    var product =   $("#ptype").val();
    var shipment    =   $("#shipment").val();
    var amount  =   parseFloat($("#price").val());
    var fee =   fees[product.toLowerCase()+"_"+shipment.toLowerCase()];
    var fee_amount;

    if(shipment.length  >=  2   &&  product.length  >=  2) {
        if(fee !== null && fee !== undefined) {
            fee =   parseFloat(fee);
            fee_amount  =   (fee/100)*amount;

            $("#shipment_cost").html(fee_amount);
            $("#total_price").html(parseFloat((amount-fee_amount)));
        } else {
            alert(shipment + " option is not available with " + product);
            $("#shipment_cost").html("0.00");
            $("#total_price").html("0");
        }
    }

}
</script>
  <form action="payment.php">
    <label>Please select your product type</label>
    <select name="product-type" id="ptype" onchange="_shipment_fee();">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="Food">Food</option>
    <option value="Furnitures">Furnitures</option>
    <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
    <option value="Computers">Computers</option>
    </select>

    <label>Shipment System</label>
    <select name="shipment" id="shipment" onchange="_shipment_fee();">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="DHL">DHL (4-5 days)</option>
    <option value="FedEx">FedEx (4-5 days)</option>
    <option value="Post">Regular Post (15-30 days)</option>
    </select>

    <label>Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount" onchange="_shipment_fee();" id="price">

    <!-- here I want to put amount of money. its will be use for shipment costing. -->

    <label>Shipment Cost</label>
    <span class="text_decoration" id="shipment_cost">0</span>$
    <!-- I think here will be automatically added shipment %, when user select product type and shipment system. -->

    <!-- Shipment cost % automatically added with total price. so total price will be amount + shipment cost. -->

    <label>Total Price</label>
    $<span class="text_decoration" id="total_price">0</span>

    <button id="payment" name="submit">Confirm & Pay</button>

    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sidstar . You are really a genius. Thanks again. Very easy tutorial for me.